# Passing special characters to a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have an encryption routine that generates an encrypted string from 2 variables. This string may or may not contain "special characters". The ones in particular that give me trouble are apostrophes and brackets.

I currently use the `[ ]` to encapsulate the argument in my execute command. But that doesn't always work.

Does anyone have a good solution to try and stop the error from getting thrown when and end bracket gets assigned?

Comment: Are you using string concatenation in your procedure? Can you should us any code?

Comment: thePWD = encrypt(request("ap"), request("al"));
set rs = cn.execute("EXEC UpdateUser  @uu_pswrd=[" & thePWD & "]);

Example - I get a value of "9]Z{Ì3™"

Comment: Yup, this is a string concatenation issue. Do you have the ability to edit the underlying SQL stored procedure?

Comment: I do - but it just pulls random...I was thinking that I'd take the final product and replace the [ ] or ' with something else....

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the problem. Are you getting an error when passing special characters *in*, or do you have an issue when the procedure *returns* these special characters?

Comment: The error occurs when it passes the execute line...so if I were to replace the variable...it bombs at:     set rs = cn.execute("EXEC UpdateUser @uu_pswrd=[9]Z{Ì3™]);  Which makes sense - cause you can see where the "end bracket" ends it.  I use the brackets so that it handles the apostrophe.  I tried apostrophe's (quotes) to encapsulate the string - but that obviously also causes problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution would just be to escape apostrophes in your input string:

```
thePWD = encrypt(request("ap"), request("al"))
set rs = cn.execute("EXEC UpdateUser @uu_pswrd='" & replace(thePWD, "'", "''") & "'")
```

A more robust way of handling this would be to add proper parameter handling to your code. This may not be exactly right, since it's been a while since I've done this with VBA/VB6, but it should get you close:

```
thePWD = encrypt(request("ap"), request("al"))

set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
cmd.CommandText = "UpdateUser"
cmd.CommandType = "StoredProcedure"
cmd.Parameters.Add(
  cmd.CreateParameter("@uu_pswrd", adVarChar, , 255, thePWD))
set rs = cmd.execute
```

Comment: That'll hopefully work...It is the only logical answer to this encryption routine...I'll give that a whirl...and let you know how it goes.  Thank You Jeff!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with verbatim literal strings?

```
@"\somestring""";
```

http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-literal

Comment: Thanx!  So - if I have a string like this...  "Dkvvy]866&*43" (notice the "end bracket")  my execite command would look like:  thePWD = Dkvvy \n] 866&*43"; set rs = cn.execute("EXEC UpdateUser @uu_pswrd=[" & thePWD & "]  ???  Sorry - I'm learning...

Comment: Sorry, just realized now that you're talking about vb6, my comment is for .Net